# Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

Hello beautiful programmers! I am facing an issue which i am unable to resolve.Please help me.  I am trying to scrape an olx.com.pk using [this link](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/develop-your-first-web-crawler-in-python-scrapy-6b2ee4baf954) but i am getting no result at all.Please help me, I would be very thankful to you.
I have tried different things but it won't work.PLEASE HELP ME.

P.S : I have checked it on scrapy shell

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from olx.items import OlxItem

class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "electronics"
    allowed_domains = ["www.olx.com.pk"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.olx.com.pk/computers-accessories/'
    ]
 rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.pageNextPrev',)),
             callback="parse_item",
             follow=False),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item_links = response.css('.large > .detailsLink::attr(href)').extract()
        for a in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(a, callback=self.parse_detail_page)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract()[0].strip()
        price = response.css('.pricelabel > strong::text').extract()[0]

        item = OlxItem()
        item['title'] = title
        item['price'] = price
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```

OUPUT IS LIKE THIS :

```
 scrapy crawl electronics
2018-07-10 14:29:33 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: olx)
2018-07-10 14:29:33 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2018-07-10 14:29:33 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'olx.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['olx.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'logs/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'olx'}
2018-07-10 14:29:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2018-07-10 14:29:34 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-07-10 14:29:35 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6028
2018-07-10 14:29:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.olx.com.pk/computers-accessories/> (referer: None)
2018-07-10 14:29:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.olx.com.pk/computers-accessories/?page=2> (referer: https://www.olx.com.pk/computers-accessories/)
2018-07-10 14:29:38 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-07-10 14:29:38 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 601,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 54431,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 10, 9, 29, 38, 323590),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 10, 9, 29, 35, 178414)}
2018-07-10 14:29:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Take a big breath and edit your post please. Due to all the CAPS and help screams you put there it is difficult to understand what you did. Please describe your problem. Tell us what you have tried until now. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by stranac the css selector seems to be wrong. 
With a nongeneric one there:

```
item_links = response.css('li[class*=lpv-item\ offer\ onclick] > .lpv-item-link::attr(href)').extract()
```

The URLs from the products will be shown.

And why don't parse the site at this step direct, you don't need to make a new request.

Comment: It is only getting 42 results. how can I get 1000 results?

Comment: I only checked the part with item_links. The Rule for pageNext has to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your css selector in `parse_item()` is not matching anything.

Looking at the page, I can see links with a class of `detailsLinkPromoted`, but not `detailsLink`.

Also, if you're already using a `CrawlSpider`, why write code for manual link extraction, instead of simply creating another rule?

Comment: actually I am a noob.I just started learning i was just following this https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/develop-your-first-web-crawler-in-python-scrapy-6b2ee4baf954 .